# Problema ao criar uma imagem com fundo transparente

Tags: php, gd

Olá,

Estou tentando criar uma imagem em PHP igual dos emails de ofertas enviados automaticamente pela CasasBahia.

Exemplo das CasasBahia;

[image: Exemplo das CasasBahia]

Procurei pela internet e achei o seguinte código que me ajudou bastante;

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$text = 'R$ 10,90';
$font = 'arial.ttf';
$image  = imagecreatetruecolor(187, 44);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 70, 140);
$background = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagettftext($image, 25, 0, 0, 33, $color, $font, $text);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $background);
imagecolortransparent($image, $background);
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Porém, quando coloquei o link do script no lugar de uma imagem que seria o real preço do produto, a imagem estava com pixels pretos ao redor do texto.

Pré-visualização do script;

[image: Pré-visualização do script]

Procurei pela internet e em fóruns porém não encontrei nada.

Estou usando o XAMPP na versão 5.6.35

Uso o Google Chrone na versão 65.0.3325.181 (última)

Comment: Posta uma imagem ai de como está a renderização na tela. E em que browser está testando?

Comment: Adicionado @hugocsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta aplicar:

```
imagesavealpha($image, true); //canal alpha
imagealphablending($image, false); //Desabilita a mesclagem
```

- `imagesavealpha`: Define a opção para salvar a informação completa do alpha channel (ao invés de a transparência de uma cor só) quando estiver salvando imagens PNG.
- `imagealphablending` habilita ou desabilita o modo de mesclagem

Deve ficar assim:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
$text = 'R$ 10,90';
$font = 'arial.ttf';

$image  = imagecreatetruecolor(187, 44);

imagesavealpha($image, true); //canal alpha
imagealphablending($image, false); //Desabilita a mesclagem

$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 70, 140);
$background = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);

imagefill($image, 0, 0, $background);
imagecolortransparent($image, $background);

imagettftext($image, 25, 0, 0, 33, $color, $font, $text);

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Veja o resultado:

[image: resultado com imagesavealpha e imagealphablending]

Comment: Valeu! Funcionou perfeitamente.

Quando colei o código aqui, dentro do número  e da letra R o fundo estava preto, então coloquei acima de `imagettftext` o `imagefill` e `imagecolortransparent` e pronto!

Comment: @GustavoDias estranho, aqui funcionou normal, pode ser um bug da sua versão do PHP ou outra coisa, de qualquer forma aprovei sua edição para a resposta.