# Como salvar imagens ".png" sem fundo preto no php?

Tags: php

bom dia!

Sou novo no php e, se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço. Estou salvando as imagens, mas, quando elas possuem fundo transparente, após o salvamento, ficam com fundo preto. A função que estou usando é essa:

```
    function redimensionarImg($imagem_temporaria, $largura, $altura) {
    $largura_original = imagesx($imagem_temporaria);
    $altura_original = imagesy($imagem_temporaria);

    $nova_largura = $largura ? $largura : floor(($largura_original / $altura_original) * $altura);

    $nova_altura = $altura ? $altura : floor(($altura_original / $largura_original) * $largura);

    $imagem_redimensionada = imagecreatetruecolor($nova_largura, $nova_altura);

    imagecopyresampled($imagem_redimensionada, $imagem_temporaria, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nova_largura, $nova_altura, $largura_original, $altura_original);

    return $imagem_redimensionada;
}
```

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291634/problema-ao-criar-uma-imagem-com-fundo-transparente

Answer (score 0):

As seguintes funções nativas podem te ajudar.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_file);

//Trata transparência para PNG
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagecolortransparent($image);

//Salva imagem já com fundo transparente
imagepng($image, $path_to_save);
```

Comment: Com o perdão da ignorância não consegui usar :-(

Comment: Coloca os erros pra gente ver como te ajudar...